# Kendall's coefficient of concordance (W) in Python

Tags: python, r, function, statistics

I'm trying to calculate Kendall coefficient of concordance (W) from my data. Is anyone aware of a function implemented in a Python package as in the "vegan" package of R (http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/kendall.global.html), including a permutation test?

Kendall's W is not difficult to calculate, but I can't find a Python function that allow to combine it with a permutation test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PLEASE NOTE: I am indebted to Boris for finding an error in this code. In the line where `S` is calculated I inadvertently multiplied by `m` rather than `n`.

I don't know of one either. However, you can calculate the permutation test in Python in this way. Note that I have not included the correction for tied values in the formula for 'W'.

```
import numpy as np

def kendall_w(expt_ratings):
    if expt_ratings.ndim!=2:
        raise 'ratings matrix must be 2-dimensional'
    m = expt_ratings.shape[0] #raters
    n = expt_ratings.shape[1] # items rated
    denom = m**2*(n**3-n)
    rating_sums = np.sum(expt_ratings, axis=0)
    S = n*np.var(rating_sums)
    return 12*S/denom

the_ratings = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4],[1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2]])
m = the_ratings.shape[0]
n = the_ratings.shape[1]

W = kendall_w(the_ratings)

count = 0
for trial in range(1000):
    perm_trial = []
    for _ in range(m):
        perm_trial.append(list(np.random.permutation(range(1, 1+n))))
    count += 1 if kendall_w(np.array(perm_trial)) > W else 0

print ('Calculated value of W:', W, ' exceeds permutation values in', count, 'out of 1000 cases')
```

In this case the result was,

```
Calculated value of W: 0.575  exceeds permutation values in 55 out of 1000 cases.
```

You should also note that, since these are random permutations there will be some variation in the number of values reported. For instance, in one of the trials I made I think the calculated value of 0.575 exceeded only 48 out of 1000 cases.

Comment: what exactly is the_ratings and how do you end up with it?

Comment: @Boris: Four Ss have each been asked to rank four items. `the_ratings` are the resulting data. Each of the four sublists in `the_ratings` is the set of rankings for one S.

Comment: So all the sublists rank the elements in the same order right? the_ratings[0][1] corresponds to the_ratings[1][1]?

Comment: BelI just tried this with exprratings = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] and got a measure of 0.4. I think something might be wrong.

Comment: @Boris: Many thanks for your courteous notice and for staying with me on this. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If there are 'm' raters and 'n' items, shouldn't it be a multiplication by 'n' instead of 'm' in 'S'?

```
S = n*np.var(rating_sums)
```

I believe it went by unnoticed because you are using 4 raters and 4 items in your example, so 'm = n'. I noticed because I was using this code and getting values over one.

Comment: Yes, it should. I've finally seen this. Since you seem new to SO you might not know that this would have been better as a comment to my answer. Then I would have seen it much sooner. Thanks for your help with this.